# Can't log into Unity on both Unity Hub and Unity website

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication

I can't seem to log into Unity on both Unity Hub (version 3.1.2) as well as Unity's official website. On both, a page which pops up has this message:

> "Sorry, this link is no longer valid. Conversation Ip Violation,
> conversation Ip:223.238.xxx.xx, User Ip:27.63.xxx.xx."

(I have left out my IP details for privacy reasons). I have tried unblocking unityhelper as well as unity hub on my firewall but still, the problem persists.

Comment: This is because your country's IP is on the sanctions list. I suggest using a powerful VPN like cisco. If it does not answer. Delete the unity hub and open unity directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. It was probably a glitch on my network. Restarting the Wifi as well as system fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm maybe go into Registory Editor and delete the Unity Hub file. or use a different browser to login.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).